# How do we view the feature importance in K-modes clustering in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with 12 Categorical variables and I have performed k-modes clustering on it forming 3 clusters in total. I want to view how each variable contributed for clustering.

Answer (score 1):

If the categorical variable is indeed useful for clustering, then you should be able to see an association between the categorical labels and the kmode predicted label. We can try to test this association with a chi-square test.

Using an example dataset from [kmodes soybean](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/blob/master/examples/soybean.py):

```
from kmodes.kmodes import KModes
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicodv/kmodes/master/examples/soybean.csv",header=None)
X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
X = X.loc[:,X.var() > 0]
X.columns = ['feature{}'.format(i) for i in X.columns]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]
X.iloc[:5,:5]

    feature0    feature1    feature2    feature3    feature4
0   4   0   2   1   1
1   5   0   2   1   0
2   3   0   2   1   0
3   6   0   2   1   0
4   4   0   2   1   0
```

Fit kmodes:

```
km = KModes(n_clusters=4).fit(X)
```

For each column, perform a chi-square test with the predicted labels:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
def chi_test(ds,labels):
    ct = pd.crosstab(ds,labels)    
    return chi2_contingency(ct)

res = X.apply(lambda x:chi_test(x,km.labels_)[:-1]).T
res.columns = ["chi2","p","df"]
```

we can sort the result by pvalue:

```
res.sort_values("p")

    chi2    p   df
feature20   107.823529  4.076092e-19    9.0
feature21   105.750000  1.075367e-18    9.0
feature6    71.515314   7.676489e-12    9.0
feature2    53.702317   8.470441e-10    6.0
feature3    51.052191   2.891285e-09    6.0
feature27   47.000000   3.475607e-10    3.0
feature26   47.000000   3.475607e-10    3.0
feature25   47.000000   3.475607e-10    3.0
feature22   47.000000   3.475607e-10    3.0
feature34   43.191379   2.241181e-09    3.0
feature0    42.703296   8.811983e-04    18.0
feature11   41.186842   5.968910e-09    3.0
feature1    40.573818   8.052002e-09    3.0
feature23   31.292825   7.375288e-07    3.0
feature24   20.702381   1.213722e-04    3.0
feature7    11.779102   8.179472e-03    3.0
feature9    6.907064    3.295275e-01    6.0
feature4    6.582880    8.645061e-02    3.0
feature5    4.361413    8.860574e-01    9.0
feature19   3.128446    3.722421e-01    3.0
feature8    0.437745    9.323395e-01    3.0
```

The first ranked `feature20` can pretty much separate your labels:

```
pd.crosstab(km.labels_,X['feature20'])

feature20   0   1   2   3
row_0               
        0   0   8   9   0
        1   0   0   0   10
        2   10  0   0   0
        3   0   10  0   0
```

Compared to the lower ranked `feature5`  :

```
feature5    0   1   2   3
row_0               
         0  2   5   4   6
         1  0   4   3   3
         2  2   3   2   3
         3  3   2   2   3
```